# How to switch to a different storage driver on an existing docker installation in Redhat Linux 7*

Tags: docker, daemon, dockerhub

I have under /etc/sysconfig/docker , the following configuration :-

other_args="--insecure-registry ******* -g /apps/var/lib"

Now I am using docker version 17.03.1-ce on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 and default storage driver as overlay that is causing lot of build issues due to :-

checksum_type: too many links

After doing a bit of research on the internet figured out to get rid of this the best solution would be to use overlay2 driver.

How do i edit the /etc/sysconfig/docker to include storage driver as overlay2. I tried lot of ways but none worked. I don't want to reinstall so looking for the easiest approach here that can allow me switch to overlay2 storage driver. I am sure docker tool is robust enough to allow such modifications on an existing installation.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated as always.

Comment: Do you mean RHEL 7? RH 7 is almost two decades out of date.

Answer (score 7):

you can edit config file and insert below configuration and please restart docker daemon

```html
{
  "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
```

Comment: Please create file /etc/docker/daemon.json and insert above config

Answer (score 4):

Created a file /etc/docker/daemon.json with :-

```
{
  "storage-driver": "overlay2",
  "storage-opts": [
    "overlay2.override_kernel_check=true"
  ]
}
```

And that did the trick